# Monitoring for changes in folder without continuously running

Tags: filesystems, dropbox, filesystemwatcher

This question has been asked around several time. Many programs like Dropbox make use of some form of file system api interaction to instantaneously keep track of changes that take place within a monitored folder. 
As far as my understanding goes, however, this requires some daemon to be online at all times to wait for callbacks from the file system api. However, I can shut Dropbox down, update files and folders, and when I launch it again it still gets to know what the changes that I did to my folder were. How is this possible? Does it exhaustively search the whole tree in search for updates?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is YES.

Let's use Google Drive as an example, since its local database is not encrypted, and it's easy to see what's going on.

Basically it keeps a snapshot of the Google Drive folder.
You can browse the snapshot.db (typically under `%USER%\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\user_default`) using [DB browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Here's a sample from my computer:
[image]

You see that it tracks (among other stuff):

- Last write time (looks like [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).
- [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum).
- Size - in bytes.

Whenever Google Drive starts up, it queries all the files and folders that are under your "Google Drive" folder (you can see that using [Procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

Note that changes can also sync down from the server

There's also [Change Journals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798(VS.85).aspx), but I don't think that Dropbox or GDrive use it:

> To avoid these disadvantages, the NTFS file system maintains an update sequence number (USN) change journal. When any change is made to a file or directory in a volume, the USN change journal for that volume is updated with a description of the change and the name of the file or directory.